# how to authenticate when using Google Address Validation API C# client libraries

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use Address Validation API C# client libraries.  From this page, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/client_libraries, it is required to provide credentials in Application Default credentials (ADC).  I am given Google API Key, but it is not clear how I use it to configure ADC.  Does anyone have anything to share, I would really appreciate it?

Thank you.

Tony

I am expecting instructions on how to set up ADC by using Google API key or other account information.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#authentication

Comment: I don't see specific instructions on how to set up ACS from the link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.